# How can I setup speedtracer (http://code.google.com/p/speedtracer/) developement environment in Eclispe

Tags: javascript, performance

I am looking at the possibility of using http://code.google.com/p/speedtracer/ to benchmark a JavaScript/PHP application. I need a starting point to see if:

1. Its possible to use speedtracer without using GWT ?
2. Can i write my Java code outside speedtracer environment and drive speedtracer
3. Can i get results from speedtracer as csv file, which i can plot, or use speedtracer built-in graph
4. Can speedtracer be interfaced with xshprof http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [users manual](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/get-started.html), it is a Google Chrome extension, requiring the Dev Channel version of Chrome. I don't think you will be able to use it with Eclipse. However, as long as Chrome can run your web application, I think that SpeedTracer will be able to analyze it.